# Please clarify the documentation of `StatefulWidget.build` method

Tags: flutter

In the "Performance considerations" section of StatefulWidget [documentation](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), third point mentions the following:

> If a subtree does not change, cache the widget that represents that subtree and re-use it each time it can be used. To do this, assign a widget to a final state variable and re-use it in the build method. It is massively more efficient for a widget to be re-used than for a new (but identically-configured) widget to be created. Another caching strategy consists in extracting the mutable part of the widget into a [StatefulWidget](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) which accepts a child parameter.

Its not clear that what is "state variable" here, and what to to assign, because "build" term is mentioned in that line, and there is also a `build` method for every widget,

I mean,

Should the user do `final Widget widget = MyWidget();` or `final Widget widget = MyWidget().build(context);`

As they both return `Widget`,

Also please explain, that is there any difference between the above statements, and what is the use of `Builder` widget, if we have `build` method, or do they have different work, if so, then what ???

thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, ever ever ever run the `build` method on your own, the build method is there for flutter to call for itself with an updated context, you should not be using it. Always do `MyWidget()`

The `Builder` widget is useful when you need a newer context for something inside your widget, for example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) { // context crated here
  return MaterialApp( // navigator created here, after the context was defined
    home: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()
    ), 
  );
}
```

This code won't work  because the `context` was created before the navigator (which was created along with a material app), you could wrap the button inside a builder widget to get a newer context that already has a navigator

Of course, calling the build method on your own is not good because you won't be passing the correct context to the widget, instead, let flutter handle the context creating and just use normal constructors.